# Unknown Exception. Too many Query rows

Tags: soql, exception, query

I have 3 SOQL Queries running in an Apex class.  I'm using the related VF page in Force.com sites.  When this code runs, it is throwing an exception on the page.  No exception is caught in debug logs.

However, if I add LIMIT 500 and LIMIT 250 to the SOQL queries 1 and 2 (in the below code), it is not throwing error.  My results are displayed in the VF Page (ofcourse not all records are shown because of the LIMITS I put).  So, something is related to number of records error.

I have clearly mentioned the number of records it is returning for each SOQL query in the code below, it is well within the governor limits.

What could be the problem?

```
set<Id> EngIds = new set<Id>();
List<Match__c> recMatches = new List<Match__c>(); 

//Query 1
recMatches = [SELECT Id FROM Match__c WHERE Status__c !='Requested' AND Status__c != 'Confirmed' AND Program__c = 'ASBraz'];
//795 records
if(recMatches.size()>0 && recMatches!=null){
    for(Match__c rm:recMatches){
        if(rm.Engagement__c!=null)                
            engIds.add(rm.Engagement__c);
    }
}
//EngIds size: 425


//Query 2
List<Engagement__c> npEngs = new List<Engagement__c>();
npEngs = [SELECT Id FROM Engagement__c WHERE Placement_Status__c = 'Not Placed' AND Status__c = 'Processing' AND Program__c INCLUDES ('ASChil')];
//405 records
if(npEngs.size()>0 && npEngs!=null){
    for(Engagement__c npEng:npEngs){
        engIds.add(npEng.Id);
    }
}
//EngIds size: 603



Set<Id> exEngs = new Set<Id>();
List<Match__c> reqMatches = new List<Match__c>(); 

//Query 3
if(engIds!=null && engIds.size()>0){    
    reqMatches = [SELECT Id FROM Match__c WHERE (Status__c ='Requested' OR Status__c ='Confirmed') AND Program__c = 'AsBraz' AND Engagement__c IN:engIds];    
    //177 records
    if(reqMatches.size()>0 && reqMatches!=null){
        for(Match__c m:reqMatches){
            exEngs.add(m.Engagement__c);
        }
    }
}

if(exEngs.size()>0 && exEngs!=null && engIds.size()>0 && engIds!=null){
    for(Id n:exEngs){
        if(engIds.contains(n)){
            engIds.remove(n);
        }
    }
}
//EngIds size: 426
```

Comment: try using loops as described in here https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm

Comment: But the number of records Im dealing with here are less than 1000!  This is not bulk data.

Comment: You've only listed your queries, NOT the rest of your code! We can't tell how many times your queries are called! Are they in loops, is the VF page calling them or the class calling them multiple times?? Post the rest of your code so a more intelligent answer can be provided by giving us the information needed to fully assess your situation.

Comment: Setting aside the inappropriate tone of Cal's comment, he does have a point. There are limits on total rows retrieved in the page, as well as per visualforce iterative element. IF (emphasis intended) your stated row counts are correct, then you have a curious situation, indeed. On a separate note, you may have more luck in your last IF clause by using a removeAll method instead of iterating.

Comment: Is the table itself large? You could be getting non-selective query errors caused by full table scans. You should avoid != queries because they cannot leverage any indexes. Instead, explicitly list the values you are looking for.